# Can not add invitees to a calendar event after the event has been created

Tags: calendar, ical

I can not find a way to add an invitee after the event has been created and the invite emails sent. Is it possible?

Below is the already created event, where I do not see the field to "add invitees" any more:

[image: This is the already created event, and I do not see anymore 'add invitees']

Here is an event that has not yet been created, thus possible to add invitees:

[image: This is the event that has not yet been created, thus possible to add invitees]

EDIT: I use Exchange as the backend for the calendar... though had same issues with Google Calendar as backend as well.

Using Calendar Version 9.0 (2155.15)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out the reason. I found out this statement in Apple support page (https://support.apple.com/guide/calendar/if-you-cant-change-a-calendar-or-event-on-mac-icl1033/mac):

> If you can’t change an event you created, or you can’t change your
>   status for an event you were invited to, it might be because you’re
>   using an email address in Calendar that isn’t on your card in
>   Contacts. Make sure all your email addresses are listed on your
>   Contacts card. See Edit contacts.

I decided to completely remove my Exchange account from the Internet Accounts on my mac. Then when signing again, I used as an email address my full email address: firstname.lastname@company.com and when signing to my account (via Microsoft web login) we need to use the shorter version of the email (in our company): username@company.com. It seems the problem lied in that I used short version of the email for the default email address in my calendar, which caused some permission issues etc. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue of not being able to add an invitee by exporting all my appointments and creating a new iCloud Calendar.

- go to **File** > **New Calendar** > **iCloud**
- create a new calendar
- go to **File** > **Export** > **Export...**
- export the old calendar
- go to **File** > **Import...**
- select the file to which you exported the old calendar
- click **Import**
- select the newly added calendar
- click **Ok**
- delete the old calendar

Answer (score 1):

If you click on the list of invitees, there should be an "Add Invitees" field which appears below the list.

[image][image]

Comment: But for some reason I do not see Add Invitees field, like it is shown for you. I use Exchange as the backend for the calendar... though had same issues with Google Calendar as backend as well.

Answer (score 0):

I use an Exchange account and iCloud, and I notice my iCloud events remain editable while my Exchange events get "locked" after creation. There is no way to click the list. After the event is created, all the editing functions (changing time, changing notes, adding invitees, etc) are not clickable to edit.

Answer (score 0):

I did eventually find a solution: I logged into the external calendar via browser (in my case, exchange/Outlook) and could edit there.  Apple 'Calendar' (formerly iCal) would create the event for exchange, but after a step or two could not edit, or even cancel with notifications.  (Again, I would reply to the earlier solution not working, but I can't add comment there.)

Comment: I also can edit events in other client, for example from my iPhone calendar, but using Mac OS X calendar it does not work and it is frustrating :(